# How to use support vector machines (SVM) in a dynamic environment?

Tags: classification, svm, natural-language

Base on my understanding from the SVMs, the feature vector is formed based on the whole dataset (including train and test data). In case we want to apply the trained classifier on a new set of test data, do we need to run the classification algorithm from scratch? If no, what if one of the input test vectors has a size greater than the classifier's vector size?

Comment: Provided a trained model, class prediction (or regression value) can be predicted from an unlabeled features vector. The features vector is built independently from train/test set.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask what do you mean by "the features vector is built independently from train/test set"? We use a dataset which is going to be classified to form the feature vector. Am I correct?

Comment: The basic supervised learning setting is here, nothing special for SVMs. A dataset is built from feature vectors. It just happens that the training set has the feature vectors labeled and the testing set - devoid of the labels (at least the assumption is).